# How to use an object reference in a whole class

Tags: java, reference

so for example in a switch statement "case 1" I declare an Object reference variable, its all good, but if I try to use in a "case 2" it says that reference variable cannot be resolved.

How can I use it in every case?

Edit:

```
switch(choice){ 
                case 1: {
                    if(HotelObj.getClassicRoomsAvailable() == 0 && HotelObj.getExecutiveRoomsAvailable() == 0){
                        System.out.println("Sorry, there are no available rooms");
                        break;
                    }else {
                        Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.print("\nEnter desired room type: ");
                        System.out.print ("\nEnter \"Classic\" for a classic type room, price: 90$ for a day");
                        System.out.println("\nEnter \"Executive\" for a executive type room, price: 150$ for a day");
                        String roomChoice = scanInput.nextLine();

                        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
                        String clientName = scanInput.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter for how many days you'll stay:");
                        int stayingDays = scanInput.nextInt();

                        Client ClientObj = new Client(clientName, roomChoice, stayingDays);

                        Client.clientCount++;
                            if(roomChoice.equals("Classic")){
                                ClientObj.clientRoom = new Room("Classic");
                                ClientObj.setMoney(ClientObj.getMoney()- stayingDays * ClientObj.clientRoom.getPrice());
                                HotelObj.decClassicRooms(1);
                                HotelObj.addIncome(stayingDays*ClientObj.clientRoom.getPrice());
                            } else {
                                ClientObj.clientRoom = new Room("Executive");
                                ClientObj.setMoney(ClientObj.getMoney()-stayingDays * ClientObj.clientRoom.getPrice());
                                HotelObj.decExecutiveRooms(1);
                                HotelObj.addIncome(stayingDays*ClientObj.clientRoom.getPrice());
                            }                    
                    }
                    break;
                }

               case 2: {
                   System.out.println("Name: "+ClientObj.getName());
                   //Error "ClientObj cannot be resolved"
               }
            }
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you tried?

Comment: What you describe is patently false in Java due to the way `switch` statements work. Any variable declared in a `case` is visible to all cases that follow as cases are only labels and the `switch` is the enclosing block. Please post an example of what you're trying to do, and exactly what's not working.

Comment: Post-edit: Your problem really has nothing to do with switch. You've declared a variable inside a block (`else`) which means that's the only place it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  My answer below is correct.  So is Brian's post-edit above.  Note that I agree with your practice of enclosing each case in brackets, which make your complex cases far easier to read - their demarcation from each other is clear.  While Brian's right that it's not necessary to enclose cases in brackets, IMO this is the better coding practice, and FYI it's enforced in many organizations.

Answer (score 3):

Variables you declare inside your case statements are local to that statement, so, right-o, they won't be seen outside it.  Just declare your variable before (above) the switch() and it'll be visible to them all.

Edit: this example is in response to Brian Roach below:

> ```
> public void main(String[] args) {         
>     int foo = 11;         
>     switch (foo) {        
>     case 1: {
>         int bar = 12;
>         System.out.println("1");
>         break;
>     }
>     case 2: {
>         System.out.println("2");
>         System.out.println("bar: " + bar);
>         break;
>     }
>     default: {
>         System.out.println("default");
>         break;
>     }     
> }
> ```

Compiler complains: "bar cannot be resolved to a variable"

To fix, move the declaration of bar to the same location as the declaration of foo.

Comment: In Java this is (annoyingly) incorrect. Case statements in Java are only labels, with the `switch` being the enclosing block. If you declare a variable in one `case`, it's visible to all cases after it. Given this, It's unclear what the OP is actually asking.

Comment: No, it's correct.  Example added to my answer.  Sorry that I'm having trouble formatting the code.  Fixed in a sec.

Comment: Well, yes, if you create unnecessary blocks *inside* the case, things in those blocks are only local to those blocks.

Comment: The blocks are standard good coding procedure.  They make the intention and scope of each case unmistakable.